# PHP - file_get_contents() automatically echoes to the HTML page

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a page on a remote server with the following line:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($search_url);
```

which automatically *echoes* $contents to the HTML page no matter what I do. It's as if I have done the following:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($search_url);
echo $contents;
```

What could be causing PHP to do this? Is there any configuration item that needs changing?

Comment: Do you flush the output buffer somewhere?

Comment: I have never seen this happen. I would bet good money that some of your other code is causing the problem. Please post your entire PHP page's code on a pastebin.

Comment: What is `$search_url`? By default, `file_get_contents` does not echo/print, (hence the get), it is *not* [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile).

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't flush the buffer, but I do include the problem page between a ob_start() and ob_end_clean() and capture the contents using an ob_get_contents() - is this a problem?

Comment: @hakre $search_url is an API url that goes like this: http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=B747082E2ED0&q=Yamaha+FX+Sho&location=90810®ion=usa&radius=100&format=php_serial&num=50&sort=ctime_reverse&category=vehicle/boat&DEBUG. It will return me a PHP array serialized to a string.

Comment: @ARV shouldn't be a problem. Can you post that code too, just to be sure?

Comment: that is not possible may be other part of your code cause this. if you can  put your code here we can clear your issue

Comment: @Polynomial Here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/K11QUvzA . Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @PeeHaa Here is the code it's invoked from (sorry for the indentation - it looks OK in my eclipse): http://pastebin.com/i5ghVZxn . The function is include_search_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a STUPID bug - the variable $contents is being used in the included file as well as in the function it is included from. This caused the issue - nothing wrong with file_get_contents!

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth taking a look at this bit of your code. If you comment it out, does the same thing still happen?

```
<?php if (isset($debug) && isset($ret_value)):?>
<pre>
    <?php print_r($ret_value) ?>
</pre>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This does appear to echo what you have previously fetched in the `file_get_contents()`.